# Ionic v1 webview error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When I run my app in a device and I got a blank view, but it works perfectly running on chrome (ionic serve).

So, debugging it, I got this error:

```
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.eb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (SystemWebView.java:47)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (SystemWebView.java:43)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.<init>(android.content.Context, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences) (SystemWebViewEngine.java:76)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(android.content.Context, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences) (CordovaWebViewImpl.java:79)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine() (CordovaActivity.java:206)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView() (CordovaActivity.java:202)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init() (CordovaActivity.java:146)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(java.lang.String) (CordovaActivity.java:224)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.manager.menuto.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:39)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (SystemWebView.java:47)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (SystemWebView.java:43)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine.<init>(android.content.Context, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences) (SystemWebViewEngine.java:76)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(android.content.Context, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences) (CordovaWebViewImpl.java:79)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewEngine org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine() (CordovaActivity.java:206)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView() (CordovaActivity.java:202)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init() (CordovaActivity.java:146)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(java.lang.String) (CordovaActivity.java:224)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.manager.menuto.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:39)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
12-06 11:29:40.047 19725-19725/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Randomly trying to fix it, I cleaned the app data and cache on my device. Now, the app works normally, but the error still shows up.

I'm using ionic version 1.7.16, and running on Android 7.0 (API 24).

I would like to solve this error, because if a user update my app, he would have to clean app data and cache... moreover, the error is still is present.

Searching it on ionic forum, I found this post https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recent-updates-prevent-app-from-starting/113343. But it not about ionic v1.

Comment: Hey mate, I am currently facing the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. I realized this issue doesn't happen on previous API, as Android 4.4. And once you clean app data and cache, the app works well again and new the next releases work fine too. However, when I debug, the error is still there.